# How to read TestFlight crash logs for Expo standalone app

Tags: expo

I built my React Native app fully in Expo and built with `expo build:ios`, without ever ejecting.

My app was rejected for Beta Testing in Testflight, and there are crash logs in `txt` file format, and this is the thread that crashed:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c4d10dc 0x22c4ae000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c54a094 0x22c548000 + 8340
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000022c42aea8 0x22c3d0000 + 372392
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022baf7788 0x22baf6000 + 6024
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022baf7934 0x22baf6000 + 6452
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000022bb0ee00 0x22bb09000 + 24064
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022bb03838 0x22baf6000 + 55352
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022bb038c4 0x22baf6000 + 55492
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c3747e8 0x22c314000 + 395240
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c322004 0x22c314000 + 57348
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000022c8c5c1c 0x22c81c000 + 695324
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000022c8c0b54 0x22c81c000 + 674644
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000022c8c00b0 0x22c81c000 + 671920
13  GraphicsServices                0x000000022eac079c 0x22eab6000 + 42908
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000258e30978 0x258574000 + 9161080
15  ExpoKitApp                      0x00000001007fb2d8 0x1007f4000 + 29400
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000022c3858e0 0x22c384000 + 6368
```

I can't figure out how to symbolicate these because all I have is a txt file.

I'm also concerned that even a symbolicated log will be helpful, because it looks like there's a single step, simply labeled `ExpoKitApp`, that started the crash, and I can't imagine there being much useful information that might come out of that one line.

Does anyone have experience hunting down crash bugs in an unejected Expo app?